# Use meta conditionally in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have following tag in my code

```
<meta http-equiv = "refresh" content="3"/>
```

This refreshes my page in every 3 seconds.
I want to use it conditionally.

That means first time refresh in 3 seconds and later refresh after 40 seconds.

How to achieve it??

Comment: One way to do this before the page actually loads - Use C# or ASP.net to determine if the user has already visited the page and write the value in from the server...

Comment: ^.. is the only way, if you want to do this with a `<meta>` tag. They're not updated after the head section has been parsed.

Comment: @Kinglish - could potentially use the browser's local storage to track it, rather than something server side - but I think you need to handle the refresh in JS then (which you should do for something like this anyways)

Answer (score 1):

use javascript like

```
int condition = func();
int timeIn = 0;
switch(condition){
case '<Your Value>' : time=3000;break;
.
.
.
}
setTimeout(function(){
 window.location.reload();
}, timeIn);
```